# flask python serving flask app debug mode: off как удалить

Tags: python, flask, логирование

После запуска появляется

- Serving Flask app 'pazy-script'
- Debug mode: off

вот код:

```
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.disabled = True
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')
app.logger.disabled = True
app.config['DEBUG'] = False
app.debug = False
```

ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА СРОЧНО!!!

Comment: Что у вас не так?

Answer (score 0):

Простой пример со StackOverflow:

```
from flask import Flask
import logging
app = Flask(__name__)
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```